# jboss 6.4 postgresql driver issue

Tags: postgresql, jboss6.x

I am looking for help for an issue I have been having involving a jboss datasource.

I am running Jboss EAP 6.4.0GA domain on a 64bit  CentOS 7 virtual machine. I am trying to add a postgresql datasource to a database named uat_prod but it looks like the driver is not loading correctly. I can add the datasource and when we restart the server, the server log shows:

JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.2)
JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "postgresql-9.2-1004.jdbc4.jar" (runtime-name: "postgresql-driver")

I can enable the datasource however when we test the connection we get the following error:

Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Failed to register driver for: postgresql-driver
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: postgresql-driver from [Module "deployment.postgresql-driver:main" from Service Module Loader]

Thanks for taking a look.

/opt/jboss-eap-6.4/domain/configuration/domain.xml

```
<datasources>
    <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/comp/env/jdbc/conuat_prod" pool-name="conuat_prod" enabled="true" use-ccm="false" statistics-enabled="false">
        <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/uat_prod</connection-url>
        <driver-class>postgresql-driver</driver-class>
        <driver>postgresql-driver</driver>
        <pool>
            <min-pool-size>0</min-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>25</max-pool-size>
            <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>jboss</user-name>
        </security>
        <validation>
            <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
            <background-validation>false</background-validation>
        </validation>
        <timeout>
            <set-tx-query-timeout>false</set-tx-query-timeout>
            <blocking-timeout-millis>0</blocking-timeout-millis>
            <idle-timeout-minutes>0</idle-timeout-minutes>
            <query-timeout>0</query-timeout>
            <use-try-lock>0</use-try-lock>
            <allocation-retry>0</allocation-retry>
            <allocation-retry-wait-millis>0</allocation-retry-wait-millis>
        </timeout>
        <statement>
            <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
        </statement>
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
        <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
            <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
    </drivers>
</datasources>
```

/opt/jboss-eap-6.4/modules/system/layers/base/org/postgresql/main/module.xml

(postgresql-9.3-1100.jdbc4.jar is also in this main dir)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.postgresql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="postgresql-9.3-1100.jdbc4.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies><module name="javax.api"/></dependencies>
</module>
```

server log:

[Server:posuat] 10:15:55,030 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:356) [ironjacamar-jdbc-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:304) [ironjacamar-jdbc-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:834) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:379) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.internalTestConnection(AbstractPool.java:728) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool.testConnection(OnePool.java:89) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.common.pool.PoolOperations$TestConnectionInPool.invokeCommandOn(PoolOperations.java:143) [jboss-as-connector-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.common.pool.PoolOperations$1.execute(PoolOperations.java:82) [jboss-as-connector-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:702) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:537) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:338) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:314) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1144) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:331) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:201) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.TransactionalProtocolOperationHandler.internalExecute(TransactionalProtocolOperationHandler.java:235) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.TransactionalProtocolOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.doExecute(TransactionalProtocolOperationHandler.java:175) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.TransactionalProtocolOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1.run(TransactionalProtocolOperationHandler.java:138) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.TransactionalProtocolOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1.run(TransactionalProtocolOperationHandler.java:134) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
[Server:posuat]         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
[Server:posuat]         at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:83) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.TransactionalProtocolOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$2$1.run(TransactionalProtocolOperationHandler.java:154) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.TransactionalProtocolOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$2$1.run(TransactionalProtocolOperationHandler.java:150) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
[Server:posuat]         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.TransactionalProtocolOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$2.execute(TransactionalProtocolOperationHandler.java:150) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.AbstractMessageHandler$2$1.doExecute(AbstractMessageHandler.java:298)
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.AbstractMessageHandler$AsyncTaskRunner.run(AbstractMessageHandler.java:537)
[Server:posuat]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
[Server:posuat]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
[Server:posuat]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:posuat] Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Failed to register driver for: postgresql-driver
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getDriver(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:654) [ironjacamar-jdbc-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:317) [ironjacamar-jdbc-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:posuat]         ... 31 more
[Server:posuat] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: postgresql-driver from [Module "deployment.postgresql-driver:main" from Service Module Loader]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:posuat]         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
[Server:posuat]         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
[Server:posuat]         at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getDriver(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:640) [ironjacamar-jdbc-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:posuat]         ... 32 more

Answer (score 0):

You can find datasource example configurations for several databases in [EAP 6 Administration and Configuration Guide - 6.8. Example Datasources](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.4/html-single/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/index.html#sect-Example_Datasources).
I propose to check there first.